# Exponential mapping in linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

i am studying Functional Analysis.
My teacher gives me a definition of exponential mapping

Let $X$ is a banach space. $A \in L(X,X)$. We define
$e^{A}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{A^n}{n!}$

He told that we can prove 
If $A,B \in L(X,X)$ and $AoB=BoA$ , $e^{A+B}=e^{A}o e^{B}=e^{B}o e^{A}$
But i don't know how to prove this statement. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the claim with Cauchy products. Compute $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{A^n}{n!}) \circ (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{B^n}{n!})$ as in the case of scalars. Observe that if $A$ and $B$ commute then $(A+B)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n C(n,k) A^k \circ B^{n-k}.$

Comment: Do you mind writing a full solution ?